# Using virsh to control VMs created in virt-manager

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, virt-manager, virsh

here's a question for you that's been driving me round the bend. I've managed to find plenty of resource from folk that want to do the opposite from me i.e see a machine they created using `virsh` in `virt-manager`.

However, I have a couple of VMs that I created through `virt-manager` that I now need to control using `virsh`.

When I use e.g. `virsh start <vm-name>` it fails claiming the domain isn't found.

`virsh list --all` returns nothing.

If it makes any difference, the storage volumes I created have been moved to a sub-directory on my `/home` partition.

Also, `libvirtd` is definitely running and the machines can still be controlled and accessed with `virt-manager`.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have used different credentials when using `virsh` and `virt-manager`. Do everything under your user, or at least the same user every time instead. `virt-manager` and `virsh` are interfaces to the same `libvirt` VM database, but the user context makes a difference, so if you want to manage the same set of VMs, always use the same user with both utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I ran a `find / -name <vm-name>.xml` and discovered that the xml files for my VMs were stored in `/etc/libvirt/qemu`.

So I ran `virsh create /etc/libvirt/qemu/<vm-name>.xml` and the VM was immediately loaded into virsh *along with* all of my other VMs.

I cannot currently figure out *exactly* why this fixed the issue. However, perhaps carrying out the above gave virsh a new location to look for xml files that it wouldn't normally check before.

Leaving this up here in the likelihood that someone else ends up in a similar situation.

By all means, if you know the exact reasoning behind this, let me know or add your own answer.

Comment: Did you run virsh in cli and virt-manager in GUI under the same user?

Comment: After your comment I went and checked. I ran virsh as root and virt-manager as my regular user but after doing the virsh create I mentioned it works for root but not my regular user. I have no way of knowing now whether it worked for the regular user beforehand.

Comment: in short - do everything under your user, or at least the same user every time. virt-manager and virsh are interfaces to the same libvirt VM database, but the user context makes a difference, so if you want to manage the same set of VMs, always use the same user with both utilities

Comment: Cheers man, it was more a mistake that came as a by-product of trying to do several things at once.